# Cannot SSH into new computer running CentOS 6.3 from Fedora 16

Tags: centos

I just installed CentOS 6.3 on a new computer and am unable to SSH to it from our computer running Fedora 16. They are both on the same network.

Some facts:
- I can ping it from the Fedora machine.
- I can SSH to the CentOS computer to itself on the CentOS computer.
- I have looked into hosts allow and deny, I have set selinux to be permissive, I tried with iptables disabled on the Fedora computer

I am fresh out of ideas...

Thanks

Comment: you should probably paste in the actual command, response as that would help clarify details.  Specifically, what user are you trying to connect as?

Comment: ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused

Comment: OpenSSH_5.8p2, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xxx [xxx.xx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Connection refused

Comment: This is the output of: ssh -vv user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx

Comment: The user is a non-root user (my name account)

Comment: The problem is one of these issues here:
[SSH config][1]


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/299051/what-does-this-ssh-error-mean

Answer (score 4):

Do you have fail2ban running?

Do you have denyhosts running?

Do you have iptables allowing TCP 22?

Do you have a line in your sshd_config that refers to "AllowUsers"? (most dont but some do, and if yours does, you need your account listed on that line)

Can you run this command **tail -f /var/log/secure** on that machine at the same time while trying to login from the second machine and spot the issue? If not, paste the output from that log here for me to comment on.

A long shot, but you might try **service sshd restart** and try again to see if that helps. Go ahead and run **tail /varlog/messages** while restarting that daemon to see if you spot anything unusual while doing that. If you spot the issue great, if you dont, post the output here for me to comment on.

Last, do this **cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config.back** and then take a good known working sshd_config from another machine and place it over the top of yours and then restart the daemon again & try again.

My money is on seeing something that helps us in **/var/log/secure**.

Comment: I'm having the exact issue, nothing in secure, my ipaddress doesn't show up as even an attempt, but there are others in there ( break in attempts).  restarted sshd no change, still connection refused.